# nopCommerce IProductService returns IList instead of IQueryable

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

The ProductService class in nopCommerce has a method GetAllProducts which returns an IList containing all products.

Wouldn't it make far more sense to return the IQueryable instead? That way I could further filter the query myself.

See code below --

```
    public virtual IList<Product> GetAllProducts(bool showHidden = false)
    {
        var query = from p in _productRepository.Table
                    orderby p.Name
                    where (showHidden || p.Published) &&
                    !p.Deleted
                    select p;
        var products = query.ToList();
        return products;
    }
```

Why convert it to a list when the IQueryable is perfectly sufficient? I cannot understand the rationale behind this.

Given this particular limitation, is there a way to work around this without modifying the Nop.Services code?

For example, I'd like to run a query to get all products created within the last 5 days. I see no way of doing this through the IProductService interface.

Is there a simple way of doing something like this?

Comment: Since you've got the source to the method already, why not just add yourself an extension method that doesn't returns the query instead?

Comment: the _productRepository variable is private, can an extension method access private variables? I never thought of this idea..

Comment: It doesn't look like they can without some sort of hackery

Comment: I suggest posing the question in the eCommerce forum, maybe there is a legitimate reason they handled it that way.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

Example:

```
var products = _productService.GetAllProducts().Where(p => p.CreatedOnUtc > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-5));
```

Comment: No, you've not understood the question at all.

Comment: I gave you a solution. After there any other way to do it. For example, in recreating a new service.

Comment: You didn't give a solution to my problem, you told me how to do exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: In this case you must create a service reference and the dependency registrar. This is a plugin?